# How to display Date time with Time Zone in Angular

Tags: angular, date, time, timezone

I am using the following code in my angular app to display Date Time with Time Zone.
it displays, July 22, 2022 12:36:52 GMT-4
I want to replace GMT-4 with specific time zone dynamically say , EDT or PST or CST

I am using the following code,

```
@Component({
    selector: '',  
    styleUrls: [''],
    templateUrl: '',
    providers: [DatePipe]
})

public class Test {
    clock;
    constructor() {
    this.clock = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'MMMM d, y h:mm:s z');
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is not possible per Angular's [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#format-examples) doc. You can do it with one of time management libraries like `moment` or `dayjs`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of pipes/custom pipes like this way:

script.js:

```
var toUTCDate = function(date){
    var _utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
    return _utc;
  };
  
  var millisToUTCDate = function(millis){
    return toUTCDate(new Date(millis));
  };
  
  var tzOffsetMillis = function(){
  var date = new Date();
  var offsetMinutes = date.getTimezoneOffset();
  var offsetMillis = offsetMinutes * 60000;
  }
  
    $scope.toUTCDate = toUTCDate;
    $scope.millisToUTCDate = millisToUTCDate;
    $scope.tzOffsetMillis = tzOffsetMillis;
```

index.html:

```
<body>
   <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <div>
         utc: {{millisToUTCDate(1400167800 * 1000) | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm Z'}}
      </div>
      <div>
         local: {{(1400167800 * 1000) | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm Z'}}
      </div>
      <div>
         alt UTC: {{(1400167800 * 1000 + tzOffsetMillis()) | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm Z'}}
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Refer: https://plnkr.co/edit/eLwnLZReCy8HXtJyO84q?p=preview&preview

Comment: thank you. I don't want to display -0400 which is GMT. I want to display EST/PST/CST tme zone

Comment: var displayTime = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(this.today, 'dd:MM:yyyy hh-mm-ss', 'GMT+1')

Comment: Or, to be more specific: moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).zoneAbbr() //IST

Comment: {{ date_expression | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy': '+0900'}}